# Phone stopped working, Cant turn it on, Solid red light, weird r/g/b/w stripes

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, troubleshooting

yesterday i had a videochat call from messenger. I had this call about 2mins and then i saw i've got 8percents of battery. My phone usually drops from 8% to 2% but this is not the main problem. When i saw i had 8percents, i plug-in the charger to the wall and then plug-in the micro usb cable to the phone.

After connecting, i got red diode but isomething very weird happend to screen. On screen, there was multiple white/r/g/b (Like few on top, few on bottom but i think in the middle it was ok) strips and the aspect ratio of screen was too weird. It was mooved to right bottom corner.

The phone stopped responding so i pressed down power button for 10secs to turn off the phone. However, when i want to turn it on back, the phone was completly dead. I tried charging it from wall like 10 mins, then from computer like 30 mins but nothing worked. I left the phone charging over night about 8hours but still nothing.

//Before trying this i removed sim-card and sd-card//

I tried all variants like power +volume-up +volume-down, power +volume-up, power +volume-down, volume-up +volume-down but nothing worked.
//I tried to hold it down like for 15-30secs, 20secs, 1minute, pushing it while charging but still nothing//

Phone: ZTE NX597J
I bought it 4months ago so i think i must go to repair shop. However, some ideas? :D

//When i connect the phone to computer or wall, i have SOLID red light. It does not blinking//
//I cant remove the battery//
//The buttons like home, back and list of applications running on backround is from android so i cant make any different variations exept for power, volume-up, volume down//

Answer (score 0):

The [key combination](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/zte/zte-nubia-n1/hardreset/first-method/) you want is volume up and power. However, there's a few things to know:

- do this while the phone is 100% off. If you're not sure, press and hold the power button. Some phones (like my Galaxy S4) enter a weird state once they are disconnected after getting charged while off.
- do this while the phone is NOT plugged in
- hold the volume up key first, and while holding it (half a second is enough), don't let go of it, just start pressing and holding the power button while still holding the volume up button. The order is important. Yes, you are holding both buttons together, but volume up needs to be pressed FIRST, otherwise the phone will only do the power button thing.